# Panel indicator for Totem (default movie player) or for audio playing?

Tags: 11.10, sound, indicator, music-player

Sometimes I mute the volume and forget a song or internet radio station is playing.  I need a visual cue to tell me the song is playing in the background while in mute.

Is there an indicator for audio/sound that is playing?

Answer (score 1):

In case you use Gnome Shell, there is [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/142/output-device-chooser-on-volume-menu/) that might do what you want.

The version 6 of that extension should provide a volume control per application, but it **has not** been released (as of today).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method I found using Unity: Install the `indicator-sysmonitor` indicator and have it run a script that checks the sound.

I haven't written a script yet, but here is how to do it if you use `pulseaudio`: https://superuser.com/questions/393448/detecting-audio-playing-in-a-bash-script

Run the custom script with `indicator-sysmonitor`: http://www.tuxgarage.com/2011/10/system-monitor-multiload-appindicators.html (second half of the article)